# Using a byte array to create an AudioInputStream

Tags: java, arrays, java-io, javasound

I'm still working of my small project to create a mixing console in JAVA and I have a new obstacle.
I'm trying to create an audioInputStream from a byteArray and then, read it to hear the sound. But there's something wrong in my code : I don't hear anything.

Here is my code :

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

public class SoudTest {
private SourceDataLine sLine;
private AudioFormat audioFormat;
private AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
private AudioInputStream audioInputStream2;
private ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream= new ByteArrayOutputStream();;
private File file = new File ("test.wav");
private File file2 = new File ("test2.wav");
SoudTest () {
    /*
     * The aim of this code is to test the possibility or creating a mixing console in JAVA like the physical mixing consoles
     * First step : Create an inputstream from a file, a microphone or anything else
     * This is like plugging a source to a line-in of a stripe of a mixing console
     * Second : Reading this input stream and create a byte array
     * This byte array will be sent to the "master output" of the mixing console
     * Question to answer later : how to create a byte array that will act like a buffer for the next steps...
     * Third : Using this byte array to create an audioInputStream
     * This step is like having the "master volume" getting what is sent by the stripe.
     * Fourth : reading this audioInputStream
     * The sound should flow out to the speaker
     */

    //1st step      
    try {
        audioInputStream=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    AudioFileFormat.Type targetType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;

    //2nd step
    try {
        AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, targetType, byteArrayOutputStream);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Finally...");
        //tLine.close();
        System.out.println("Line closed");
        try {
            audioInputStream.close();
            System.out.println("Stream closed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //3rd step
    System.out.println("Size of the outputStream : "+byteArrayOutputStream.size());
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    System.out.println("Size of byte array : "+byteArray.length);
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);

    audioFormat = new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 2, true, false);
    audioInputStream2=new AudioInputStream(bis, audioFormat, 1024);

    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
    try  {
        //System.out.println(info);
        sLine=(SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        System.out.println(sLine.getLineInfo());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        sLine.open(audioFormat);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sLine.start();
    System.out.println("Line Started");


    //4th step
    try {
        byte bytes[] =  new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead=0;
        int loop=0;
        while ((bytesRead=audioInputStream2.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length))!= -1) {
            //getVolumeLevel(bytes);
            try {
                sLine.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
                System.out.println(loop);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            loop+=1;
        }
        System.out.println("No bytes anymore !");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    System.out.println("Line stopped");
}
```

}

Here is the output in my console :

Finally...
Line closed

Stream closed.

Size of the outputStream : 35527724

Size of byte array : 35527724

interface SourceDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian, and buffers of 0 to 1000000 bytes

Line Started

0
1
2
3

No bytes anymore !
Line stopped

My original file have a size of 35.5 Mo and my byte array have a length of 35.527.727 so, it looks possible. Then, my "chunk" array have a size of 1024 so, I'm expecting around 37700 loop. So why does my "loop count" stop at "3" ?

I hope my code is clear enouth with the comments. Thank you for your help ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok,I assume : I'm stupid. When I create my audioInputStream2, I just didn't take enough care of the last parameter.

Instead of : `audioInputStream2=new AudioInputStream(bis, audioFormat, 1024);`

I should have written : `audioInputStream2=new AudioInputStream(bis, audioFormat, byteArray.length);`